# ASP.NET2 ViewModel not Updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using the NerdDinner MVC1 code.  Created a viewmodel called DinnerFormViewModel:

```
public class DinnerFormViewModel
    {
        public Dinner Dinner { get; private set; }
        public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

        public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner)
        {
            Dinner = dinner;
            Countries = new SelectList(PhoneValidator.Countries, dinner.Country);
        }
    }
```

I pass to my edit view fine which uses strongly typed helpers in MVC2.  Passing back however:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            Dinner dinnerToUpdate = dr.GetDinner(id);
            try
            {
                UpdateModel(dinnerToUpdate, "Dinner"); // using a helper becuase of strongly typed helpers to tell it what to update
                                                // updates the properites of the dinnerToUpdate object using incoming form parameters collection.
                                                // UpdateModel automatically populates ModelState when it encounters errors
                                                // works by when trying to assign BOGUS to a datetime
              //  dinnerToUpdate.Country = Request.Form["Countries"];
                dr.Save(); // dinner validation may fail here too due to hook into LINQ to SQL via Dinner.OnValidate() partial method.

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = dinnerToUpdate.DinnerID });
            }
```

This works, however my Country doesn't get updated, becuase I'm only giving the hint to UpdateModel to update the Dinner.

Question:  How to get the country saving?

Thanks.